# Hot at both ends of three-way switch - any ideas (it's not legal I know that!)

Tags: multiway-switch

1979 house, bought in 2003. I installed three-way X10 switches with no issues in 2003. They switch a pair of spotlight cans (now upgraded to LED spots) which are in a vaulted ceiling - so I cannot see where wiring goes - or get to it easily from a ladder.

2006 a wall was demo'd after water damage, and one of these switches was moved and put in a column which is all wood frame (so I cannot get into the wall to see what is going on). Came to upgrade to newer smart switches and this is what I found:

1. The "master" switch has HOT, Neutral, two travellers and LOAD - sounds sort of okay until you realize that HOT is in a 3+ground with the two travellers, and neutral in on the load to the light(s). Neutral not on the same wire as hot, not legal I believe.
2. Even worse "as found" the white traveller had been combined with the neutral - so is being used to send the neutral to the other switch box (which is the one which moved).
3. The other switch box is bizarrely even weirder. Two travellers (though one is neutral as noted above) in a 2+ground, which is different color insulation - replaced back in 2006 I am sure.
4. In addition to the white and black (taped red) traveller is a presumably mangled 1+ground! Yes a single black wire which is HOT.

Both HOTs are on the same circuit (small mercy). I cannot see any sign that there is an unused neutral in there - I suspect they pulled the other core from the 2+ground cable and that there is an illegal split somewhere in the column.

I suspect they got here by not really understanding the wiring - and playing with it until it worked (the switches seem smart enough to not care as the slave in second box has hot and neutral, all it needs to send state to the master in the other box).

So I read up on Carter, and California and other stuff ... but this thing seems to make no sense - I just have no idea how and why there is a hot on both ends. I've removed all switches, verified the travellers both ends with continuity. Verified that nothing is bridging the hot from Box 1 to Box 2.

So I could almost make this work with new switches which worked in a similar way, but it's all very weird and as I want to change out the switches would leave me knowingly breaking code in a couple of ways.

Does anyone have any idea how on earth you could end up with this config?

Comment: Smart switches don't wire like regular switches. Generally you want always-hot and neutral to serve both smart switches, so they are powered at all times.  One smart switch (master) controls the light. The other (remote) communicates with the master.  It's probably not as messed up as you think.  Harper's Rule: the last guy had reasons.

Comment: Pictures please, showing wires as you have identified them.

Comment: Sounds like what they did about a century ago adding power and a light to an out building (less wire), it is called a hot three-way. The two travelers have the 120. those would be connected to a plug or something in an out building, the third wire came from each of the switches to the light.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?